# Rails 4 model is valid, but won't save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have the following models:

## notification

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notification_path
  before_save :set_default

  def set_default
      self.resolved = false unless self.resolved
  end
end
```

## notification_path

```
class NotificationPath < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
end
```

Then this code:

> > notification = Notification.new({"area"=>"test", "severity"=>"10", "message"=>"Test", "notification_path_id" => 3})

```
 <Notification id: nil, area: "test", severity:
 10, message: "Test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil,
 notification_path_id: 3, resolved: nil>
```

> > notification.valid?
> >
> > true
> >
> > notification.errors.full_messages
> >
> > []

So, as you can see - notification is valid and has no errors. There are zero validations on the notification model. But then, when I save the model:

> > notification.save
> >
> > false

It won't save. What is causing this? It may be worth noting that `set_default` does run successfully, and even though the model isn't saving the `resolved` attribute is being set to false when it tries to save.

## EDIT

Full error trace below, when following the above in IRB:

> > > notification.save! ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved  from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in
> > >       `save!'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in`
> > >       save!'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in
> > >       `save!'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in`
> > >       block in save!'  from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in
> > >       `block in with_transaction_returning_status'  from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in`
> > >       block in transaction'    from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in
> > >       `within_new_transaction'  from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in`
> > >       transaction'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in
> > >       `transaction'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in`
> > >       with_transaction_returning_status'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activerecord-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in
> > >       `save!'   from (irb):23   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in`
> > >       start'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in
> > >       `start'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in`
> > >       console'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in
> > >       `run_command!'    from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'  from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in
> > >       `require'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`
> > >       block in require'    from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in
> > >       `load_dependency'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`
> > >       require'     from /Users/Jonathan/steel_notify/bin/rails:8:in `<top
> > >       (required)>'  from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`
> > >       load'    from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in
> > >       `block in load'   from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`
> > >       load_dependency'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@steel_notify/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in
> > >       `load'    from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
> > >       require'     from
> > >       /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
> > >       `require'     from -e:1:in`'

Comment: The quickest way to check would be to just change `save` to `save!` and see what the exception says.

Comment: @LoganSerman Thanks for the tip - I pasted my error above, nothing that jumps out to me though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby, assignments return the value being assigned. In your case you are setting `self.resolved` to `false`. When you return exactly `false` from a before_* callback, it will cancel the save operation. You need to return something that is not `false` after you make your assignment.

Comment: banging my head since last 30 minutes. Saved my life. Thanks :)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. I struggled with this when setting has_many relationships. I `franchise.businesses << business` but when I reload either business or franchise, the relationship was gone. Turns out that when you push into a collection like this, it actually performs a SQL update and since I had a `before_save` method on business that was returning false, the update was being cancelled.